# Some files from RPM have bogus permissions

Tags: permissions, rpm

I'm building RPMs with [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/wiki). One of the goals is to set the user and group of the installed files, so I'm using the `--rpmuser` and `--rpmgroup` flags.

It's working *for the most part*, however one of the directories is not receiving the desired user/group. I've run `fpm` with the `-e` flag to inspect the Spec File. All the files and directories are marked beneath the *%files* directive that should set the desired user and group - **adminuser,admingroup**.

```
%files
%defattr(-,adminuser,admingroup,-)

# Reject config files already listed or parent directories, then prefix files
# with "/", then make sure paths with spaces are quoted. I hate rpm so much.
/etc/admin-services/admin.properties
/usr/share/admin-app/static/admin-console/index.html
/usr/share/admin-app/static/admin-console/console-env.js
/usr/share/admin-app/static/admin-console/css/styles.css
/usr/share/admin-app/webapps/admin-services.war
```

After installation, all the files belong to **adminuser,admingroup** *except* the */usr/share/admin-app/static* directory (and everything beneath it), they all belong to **root,root**.

I don't think this is fpm's fault, the Spec File looks good. I believe this is an issue with rpmbuild under the hood. Any idea what could be going on?

I've read through [the documentation on Spec Files](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/s1-rpm-specref-files-list-directives.html), and I don't see any other directives that could be affecting the */usr/share/admin-app/static* directory.

Comment: Those comments in there are from the _fpm_ author btw, hilarious!

Comment: I've managed to cope via an `--after-install` flag to fpm. Therein I set the perms on the `/usr/share/admin-app/static` directory recursively. Would still like to know why the `--rpmuser` and `--rpmgroup` flags are failing though.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `--directories` option. From `fpm --help`:

```
--directories DIRECTORIES     Recursively mark a directory as being owned by the package
```

Without it, the ownership is only set for files, directories are omitted and will belong to `root:root`.

If you add `--directories /usr/share/admin-app/static` and use `fpm -e` to view the spec file, you'll see it adds the `%dir` directive which explicitly sets the permissions as you'd expect them:

```
%dir %attr(775, adminuser, admingroup) /usr/share/admin-app/static
```

And other entires for subdirectories beneath that path, if any.

Also, if you have **multiple directories** in your rpm's root (like I did), you have to use a `--directories` option for each.

This is a bit confusing, but let's thank rpm for that, not fpm's fault.